# High filter cache hit ratio despite not using "fq" param within Solr queries, why?

Tags: solr, datastax, datastax-enterprise

I'm observing high hit ratio on `dseFilterCache` in Solr web interface despite I'm not using `fq` param in my queries at all (just `q`). I don't understand why this cache is used at all (every test that runs with solr queries is incrementing cache usage values) and surprised by the high hit ratio (very close to 1). Could somebody have explanation for it?

Scenario: I'm feeding Solr via Cassandra table, I'm just making queries to Solr via http to fetch the data.

Comment: The filter cache [can also be used for other purposes](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching#filterCache) - could any of those match your use case?

Comment: Thanks Mats, apparently my case is that solr use filterCache because of sorting. When I removed sort clause the case is not being hit.